# WooCommerce additional email notification on new order with specific details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to get an extra email to the desired email address when the default WooCommerce new order is created. And want the default new order still work. Everything is ok and also getting the email.

But for custom email I am not getting the order details - I only want item details without price, customer note and order no and date.

Here is the code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_custom_order_email', 10, 1 );
function send_custom_order_email( $order_id ) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Prepare order details without prices
    $order_details = '';
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product_name = $product ? $product->get_formatted_name() : $item['name'];
        $item_quantity = $item->get_quantity();

        $order_details .= "Product: $product_name - Quantity: $item_quantity\n";
    }

    // Include the desired details in the email content
    $details_to_include = "Order Date: {$order->get_date_created()->format( 'F j, Y' )}\nOrder Number: {$order->get_order_number()}\n\nOrder Details:\n$order_details\nCustomer Note: {$order->get_customer_note()}\n";

    // Email subject and content
    $email_subject = 'New Order: ' . $order->get_order_number();
    $email_content = $details_to_include;

    // Email recipient
    $desired_email = 'desired@email.com'; // Replace with the desired email address

    // Send the desired email with the order details
    wp_mail( $desired_email, $email_subject, $email_content );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following revisited and enhanced code version:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_custom_new_order_email', 10, 2 );
function send_custom_new_order_email( $order_id, $order = null ) {
        // Get the order object if it doesn't exist
    if ( ! $order && $order_id > 0 ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    }

    $order_details = ''; // Initialize

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product        = $item->get_product(); // get the WC_Product Object
        $product_name   = $product ? strip_tags($product->get_formatted_name()) : $item->get_name(); // Product name

        // Add to the order details (for each item)
        $order_details .= "Product: {$product_name} - Quantity: {$item->get_quantity()}\n";
    }

    // Email content: Include the desired details below
    $email_content  = "Order Date: {$order->get_date_created()->format( 'F j, Y' )}\n";
    $email_content .= "Order Number: {$order->get_order_number()}\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Order Details:\n{$order_details}\n";
    $email_content .= "Customer Note: {$order->get_customer_note()}\n";

    // Email subject 
    $email_subject  = 'New Order: ' . $order->get_order_number(); 

    // Email recipient: Replace with the desired email recipient
    $desired_email  = 'someone@email.com';

    // Avoid sending the same email multiple times
    if( did_action('woocommerce_new_order') == 1 ) {
        // Send the desired email with the order details
        wp_mail( $desired_email, $email_subject, $email_content );
    }
}
```

This time it will work displaying purchased product names (with quantity) and avoiding sending the same email multiple times.